# How to login with AWS Cognito without using native SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, amazon-cognito

I want to authenticate my users using Cognito, for an app built in Flutter and Dart.

Unfortunately native AWS SDKs don't exist for Dart, and I can't use JS interop in Flutter.

I've looked at the OAuth2 flow, but that requires my users to be redirected to a login form, which isn't great for a mobile app.

What are the alternatives?

Comment: Is there any updates regarding this now in 2021?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement a backend service to validate Cognito credentials.

In this approach, you can implement a login screen in the mobile app which sends the user credentials to the backend. In the backend you can verify the credentials using Cognito SDK and issue a token that will be sent for subsequent API requests from mobile app.

You can use AWS API Gateway and Lambda to implement this.

For example refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html) to implement a NodeJS backend.

Comment: Is it okay for me to send username/password information over the network? That feels insecure.

Comment: API Gateway uses SSL to encrypt data at transit.

Comment: the example in that link is a client side example. There are no examples of getting the current user through a session token. Would you suggest storing the whole cognito user object client side and sending that for every request?

Comment: The sample code given could be also used in server side for a node js backend. if you pass the credentials to the server side and use signup or authenticateUser methods it should work.

Answer (score 17):

You can try the [amazon_cognito_identity_dart](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/amazon_cognito_identity_dart) package which is written purely in Dart.

```dart
import 'package:amazon_cognito_identity_dart/cognito.dart';

final userPool = new CognitoUserPool(
    'ap-southeast-1_xxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
final cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(
    'email@email.my', userPool);
final authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(
    username: 'email@email.my', password: 'Password001');

CognitoUserSession session;
try {
  session = await cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authDetails);
} on CognitoUserException catch (e) {
  // handle CognitoUser exceptions
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}

print(session.isValid());
```

See the [Example Secure Counter App](https://github.com/jonsaw/amazon-cognito-identity-dart/tree/master/example) to get ideas on how to use it with Flutter.

*Disclaimer: I am the original author of the package.*

Comment: Step by step instructions here: https://medium.com/@wesselsbernd/flutter-and-aws-as-of-march-2019-1ad7f40fa9e4